# Inherited classes as function parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I've got 2 classes (MyClass1 and MyClass2) that both inherit from MyBaseClass.

I want to write a function that takes a List of either of these as a parameter, like this

```
private void DoStuff(List<MyBaseClass> input)

{

...

}
```

How do I pass a List to this function?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to pass a `List<MyClass1>` or a `List<MyClass2>`, or do you want to pass a `List<MyBaseClass>` containing a mixture or `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` instances?

Comment: I  want to be able to pass a List<MyClass1> or a List<MyClass2>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it quite like that, as a `List<MyClass1>` *isn't* a `List<MyBaseClass>`. Search on Stack Overflow for generic variance for explanations of why that's the case.

One thing you *can* do is make it generic:

```
private void DoStuff<T>(List<T> input) where T : MyBaseClass
```

Alternatively, in C# 4 and .NET 4, if you only need to iterate over it, you could use `IEnumerable<T>` which is covariant in `T`:

```
private void DoStuff(IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> input)
```

Comment: I want to be able to pass a List<MyClass1> or a List<MyClass2>

Comment: @Zain: Both of the alternatives I've suggested will let you do that.

Comment: Will you please tell me that 
private void DoStuff(IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> input)
what will be parameter type of this method?

Comment: @Khan: The parameter type is `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` as shown - but you can pass in a `List<MyClass1>` due to generic covariance *if* you're using C# 4 and .NET 4.